# How is the xib associated with the OAuth controller with GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch?

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-construction, static-libraries, gdata

Converting the GData library to work with iOS is a real challenge. I have the library compiled and linked into my program, but the view for the OAuth2 sign-in is not showing up. I am using the code as described [here](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction) and shown below.

```
windowController = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch controllerWithScope:(NSString *)scope
                                                            clientID:(NSString *)clientID
                                                        clientSecret:(NSString *)clientSecret
                                                    keychainItemName:(NSString *)kKeychainItemName
                                                            delegate:(id)self
                                                    finishedSelector:@selector(windowController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:windowController
                                       animated:YES];
```

The sign-in window is not being displayed, and I suspect the xib is not linked in properly. I added the xib file `GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib` to the Groups and Files and it has a small question mark next to it after I compile. (So does the GData subproject, but I can trace execution within the subprojects files up until I try to push the view controller.)

How can I debug this?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I have the view display and fully functional when in the iOS simulator, but the view does not display at all when running on a device.